# How to access locations?

Tags: android, security, networking

I'm planning on creating android location aware app, which will access location of people with their permission. It's up to the users whether they want to share their location with others or not. So we can know where our friends are, may be we can guess what they are doing, according to their current location.

Security is major concern here, my primary aim is to create family-location network.
Guidance needed for:

1. From where can I start
2. Which API I need to use
3. Can a Google account be used for Login for my app

Comment: hi please llok on the link it will help you in a great way http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Comment: Honestly i'm new to android app development, i'm expecting positive responses. Help really appreciated.